# jQuery overlay issues

Tags: jquery

The following code allows me to close an overlay when I click on the #boxclose_4, however I would like to be able to click outside the overlay to close it as well.

```
    $('#boxclose_4').click(function(){
          box_4.animate({'top':'-400px'},500,function(){
             overlay2.fadeOut(1000);
               });
    });
```

If I add body ('#boxclose_4, body') as soon as box_4 comes down the overlay disappears and appears quickly.

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some more code? maybe the code to make the overlay appear and the css for overlay2 and the Div structure if possible. http://jsfiddle.net/ is your fiend

Comment: jsfiddle is not working right now so I will paste the code in....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add the `.overlay` as an event, not `body`

```
$('#boxclose_4, .overlay').click(function(){
      box_4.animate({'top':'-400px'},500,function(){
         overlay2.fadeOut(1000);
           });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YxhWx/1/

Comment: it still has the same issue, when I click to get the box_4 to come down the overlay at back fades in and out quickly

Comment: yep it works fine there, but on the site where I am working on, I will check if there is something else conflicting...